# pandas pivot based on unique values and criteria

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, apply

I have this dataframe:

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['123', '123', '123', '123', '123', '456'],
 'ven_group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'f', 'f'],
 'date': ['1/1/21', '2/1/21', '3/1/21', '1/1/21', '1/1/21', '1/1/21']
 })
```

[image]

I have the following criteria (this is the list ven_group that i need):

```
ven_group_li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This is the output i need:

[image]

Basically it's a pivot table with every unique id as a row with every ven_group name if it's in the ven_group_li, and then find min and max date for this ven_group, and if ven_group name is not in the list, it'll fill the row with NaN.

I tried this, but I don't know how to modify it to include my ven_group requirement and have min, max dates:

```
df_out1 = df_in.groupby('id')['ven_group'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.unique()).T).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Way:

```
unique_id = df.id.unique()
ven_group_li = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = df[df.ven_group.isin(ven_group_li)]
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'ven_group']).agg(
    [min, max]).reset_index(-1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
df1.columns = ['name', 'max', 'min']
df2 = pd.concat(
    [df1[c].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("ven_" + c + "_") for c in df1], axis=1
)
df2 = df2[sorted(df2.columns, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])].reindex(unique_id)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    ven_name_0 ven_max_0 ven_min_0 ven_name_1 ven_max_1 ven_min_1
id                                                               
123          a    1/1/21    3/1/21          b    1/1/21    1/1/21
456        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
```